# Group by a variable number of columns in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Consider the following:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(CO2)
```

What if I wanted to conditionally do:

```r
dt[, mean(conc), by = .(Type, round(uptake))]
```

OR

```
dt[, mean(conc), by = round(uptake)]
```

depending on the value of some other boolean variable `bool`? I'd just like to avoid repeating two very similar commands in an `if else` form and I'm wondering if it's possible at all with `data.table`.

I tried the following:

```
bool <- TRUE
dt[, mean(conc), by = .(unlist(ifelse(bool, list(Type), list(NULL))), round(uptake))]
```

which works in this case, but if `bool <- FALSE`, it gives this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , mean(conc), by = .(unlist(ifelse(FALSE,  : 
  column or expression 1 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type NULL. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick something:

```
gby <- c('Type', 'tmp')[c(bool, TRUE)]
dt[, tmp := round(uptake)][, mean(conc), by = gby]
```